# preg_match_all get last match

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match-all

Is it possible to get the last match using `preg_match_all`? Using this regex will only return  126 81 and that's not what I'm after. In this case I want 183 34 to be returned.

```
$string = 'Korpstigen 126 183 34 Kalmar';
preg_match_all("/[0-9]{5}|[0-9]{3} [0-9]{2}/", $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using word boundaries `\b`:

```
preg_match_all("/\b[0-9]{5}\b|\b[0-9]{3} [0-9]{2}\b/", $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

[regex101 demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/rD8mI2).

Comment: can you please explain what \b means exactly?

Comment: @JasonOOO If you click the link, there's a description on that demo site :) However, `\b` will match between a 'word' character and a non-word character. The definition of a word character here is `\w`. So, `\b` matches between `\w` and `\W` (irrespective of order). `\w` matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` (and a bunch of other 'weird' characters not commonly encountered) while `\W` matches what `\w` doesn't match. All in all, if you have `AB`, `\b` will match before `A`, it won't match between `A` and `B` and will match after `B`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to just get 183 34 and ignore all other parts of the string:

```
preg_match_all("/[0-9]{3} [0-9]{2} /", $string, $matches);
```

will return

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 183 34 
        )

)
```

I'm not sure of your needs, but if you need all three numbers

```
preg_match_all("/[0-9]{2,3}/", $string, $matches);
```

will return

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 126
            [1] => 183
            [2] => 34
        )

)
```

Comment: Nope, I need the 5 last numbers in the string and they can be formatted XXX XX or XXXXX.